# Как отключить замену кириллицы на \uXXXX в строках при конвертации в JSON

Tags: python, json, кодировка, json-encode

При попытке форматированного вывода JSON с помощью `dump`, перестают отображаться русские символы. Появляется что-то типа "произвольное поле, например Address": "\u0443\u043b\u0438\u0446\u0430 \u041c\u0430 и т.д."

Пробовал `json.dumps().encode("utf8")` и `codac convert` - ничего не помогает.

```
def load_data(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fh:  
        data = json.load(fh)  # загружаем из файла данные в словарь data
    return data

def pretty_print_json(data):
    inf = json.dumps(data,sort_keys=False,indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
    return inf
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь параметром [ensure_ascii=False](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html#json.dump):

Из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html#json.dump):

> If `ensure_ascii` is true (the default), the output is guaranteed to
>   have all incoming non-ASCII characters escaped. If `ensure_ascii` is
>   false, these characters will be output as-is.

Пример:

```
In [41]: with open(fn, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    ...:     data = json.load(f)
    ...:
    ...: print(json.dumps(data,
    ...:                  sort_keys=False,
    ...:                  indent=4,
    ...:                  separators=(',', ': ')))
    ...:
{
    "\u043f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u0440": {
        "\u0417\u0430\u0433\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0432\u043e\u043a": "\u043f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u0440 \u0441\u043b\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0440
\u044f",
        "\u0441\u043f\u0438\u0441\u043e\u043a": [
            "\u044d\u043b\u0435\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0442 1",
            "\u044d\u043b\u0435\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0442 2"
        ]
    }
}

In [42]: print(json.dumps(data,
    ...:                  sort_keys=False,
    ...:                  indent=4,
    ...:                  ensure_ascii=False,
    ...:                  separators=(',', ': ')))
    ...:
{
    "пример": {
        "Заголовок": "пример словаря",
        "список": [
            "элемент 1",
            "элемент 2"
        ]
    }
}
```

JSON file:

```
{
    "пример": {
        "Заголовок": "пример словаря",
        "список": ["элемент 1", "элемент 2"]
    }
}
```

Comment: в общем случае, `ensure_ascii` не достаточно, чтобы напечатать русский текст, например: `LC_ALL=C python -c 'print(u"\u0443")'` ведёт к `UnicodeEncodeError` ошибке или покажет как `\u0443`, если `PYTHONIOENCODING=:backslashreplace` определено (по умолчанию для stderr).