# как добавить имя и значение в json файл при текущей структуре файла?

Tags: python, json

Есть такая структура json файла:

```
{
   "dictionary": {
         "Имя1":[
            "значение1",
            "значение2"
         ],
         "имя2":[
            "значение1",
            "значение2"
         ],
         "имя4":[
            "значение1",
            "значение2"
         ]
      }
}
```

Я написал код, для того, чтобы можно было добавлять в файл новые имена и значения, но он вызывает исключение `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'dict' and 'list'`

```
a_dict = ({"имя5": ["123"]})

with open('keywords.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  data = json.load(f)

data["dictionary"] += list(a_dict)

with open('keywords.json', 'w') as f:
  json.dumps(data, f)
```

Как мне добраться до имен и добавлять их?

Comment: Зачем преобразовывать `a_dict` в тип `list`? Он ведь уже нужного типа. `data["dictionary"] += a_dict` вроде должно сработать.

Comment: Нет, такое же исключение вылезло

Comment: Вы точно сделали вот так `data["dictionary"] += a_dict`? Очень странно, что там вылезло такое же исключение, если типа поменялись? может всё-таки исключение тоже изменилось?

Comment: Да, прощу прощения за невнимательность `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'dict' and 'dict'`

Comment: Подзабыл питон уже. Вот так это делается: `data["dictionary"]["имя5"] = ["123"]`. То есть `[]` создают элемент которого ранее не было и Вы ему присваиваете уже то, что нужно

Comment: Да, ошибка ушла, это в общем-то верный ответ на мой вопрос, но не подскажите, на этой строке `data = json.load(f)` ругается на `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: Я попробовал, но у меня была другая ошибка. Гуглим Вашу и находим мегапопулярный вопрос на SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573332/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0 (см. второй ответ).

Comment: У меня этот код превратил json файл в вид: `{"dictionary": {"\u0418\u043c\u044f1": ["\u0437\u043d\u0430\u0447\u0435\u043d\u0438\u04351",...["\u0437\u043d\u0430\u0447\u0435\u043d\u0438\u04351", "\u0437\u043d\u0430\u0447\u0435\u043d\u0438\u04352"], "\u0438\u043c\u044f5": "123"}}`

Comment: Для будущего поколения, решение здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/584129/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-json-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0
В json.dumps добавить ensure_ascii=False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Элементы в словарь можно добавить с помощью оператора `[]`, который позволяет не только получить элемент по заданному ключу, но и создать элемент с заданным ключом. После чего этому элементу следует присвоить нужное значение. Для Вашего случая:

```python
data["dictionary"]["имя5"] = ["123"]
```

Здесь `data["dictionary"]["имя5"]` создаёт пустой элемент с ключом `"имя5"`, а потом присваивает ему значение `["123"]`.